# Open existing window in Gtk#

Tags: c#, .net, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have added a new window to the project and the name of the window is `Actwindow`. How can I open this window?

I tried using `Actwindow=new Window();` but it does not work.

The window code is:

```
using System;

namespace myproject
{
    public partial class Actwindow : Gtk.Window
    {
        public Actwindow () :
            base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
        {
            this.Build ();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Actwindow myWindow = new Actwindow();
myWindow.Show(); // or similar
```

Comment: I had already tried that.The issue was the namespace was not set properly.Thanks